# Digital Signage Player for Blu-ray quality?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm looking for recommendations for a digital signage player capable of playing true HD footage. I'll be running up to 4 of them on 42" LCD screens. I've had a terrible time with Mvix and many RMAs later I'm trying to find one that works as advertised.

What I've tried:

- Mvix Ceeno ($360 ea) - Bad video quality, 2-3 second delay in video looping
- Mvix DS HD Pro ($650 ea) - Requires you to use VUKUNET (NOT ADVERTISED) which downgrades video to WMV with horrible quality, even worse than the Ceeno

What I need:

- Loop without "black screen" delay
- Capable of true 1920x1080 playback of H.264 encoding, or possibly DivX

What would be nice:

- Remote updates in addition to manual updates
- Built in wifi
- Remote control for the less tech-savvy to stop/start the player

What I've been looking at:

- [LG NC1000-DABA](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833319003&nm_mc=OTC-Froogle&cm_mmc=OTC-Froogle-_-Network%20-%20Digital%20Media%20Players-_-LG%20ELECTRONICS-_-33319003)
- [ViewSonic NMP-640](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Q7GM3M)

I'm really looking for anyone with experience using one or more Digital Signage players. The false advertising by Mvix makes me weary of buying anything based on specs alone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mahdi - the Digital View ViewStream 500](http://dvsignage.com/products/viewstream-500-homepage) should meet your requirements, see. It handles both manual and remote updates both directly over a LAN or via a server over the Internet. You can find more information on [their website.](http://dvsignage.com/using-dv-studio)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was about to go with this, but the client I was working with didn't want a second round of returns.. Never again Mvix!

Answer (score 1):

We use a [mediaBOX-200 from media signage](http://mediasignage.com/html/media_players.html) and also use their software.

It is very good software – and in the box you have an Intel HD 2000 graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Popcorn Hour S-210](http://www.popcornhour.com/onlinestore/index.php?pluginoption=catalog&mainItemId=11). I don't have any experience with that particular device, but I have owned the A-110 media player for several years and was generally pleased, not because it was so great, but because there were few other choices in this segment (and still are). 
The S-210 only supports HDMI v1.1a for the video output, though. Ask them if you can get 1080p on your screens.

The only other suggestion that I have is a small-form factor PC (like the ones from Zotac) and a Windows-based software solution, such as [this one](http://www.sitec.at/default.aspx?scope=prod.sinema.spic) that a friend of mine wrote 20 years ago as an add-on to a theater management system (please excuse the thick German "accent" in the product description).